# Men won't capture anti-tank gun in the first campaign mission

Tags: company-of-heroes-2

First campaign, Stalingrad. Men get to the anti-tank gun and won't surmount the sandbags and capture the gun. tried from behind tank and adjacent to tank-gun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to right click the obsticle then troops jump it